# Laravel 5.1 - Built in password reset functionality not sending email with token

Tags: php, email, laravel, url, forgot-password

**OVERVIEW:**

I'm creating a password reset functionality using the built in system in Laravel 5.1, I have followed the instructions exactly how it says [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-routing).

The view in `resources/views/emails/password.blade.php` receives a variable `$token` which contains the password reset token to match the user to the password reset request. Within the view, I have the following code which is supposed to create a URL link of the page where the user set the new password:

```
   Click here to reset your password: {{ url('password/reset/'.$token) }}
```

**PROBLEM:**

It does not send the email at all. But I have realized that, if I remove the last trailing slash (see below):

```
   Click here to reset your password: {{ url('password/reset'.$token) }}
```

I receive something like `http://mywebsite.com/password/reset35df435dfgdfg...`

**CONCLUSION:**

Whenever there is a trailing slash between `password/reset/` and the `$token`, the email is not sent. Even when I manually type the URL.

Why would the `/` before the `$token` affect on the email being sent? Any ideas?

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS:**

```
 url('password/reset', [$token]); //DID NOT WORK

 action('Auth\PasswordController@getEmail', ['token' => $token]);  //DID NOT WORK

 route('password/email', ['token' => $token]); //DID NOT WORK

 url('password/reset/'.$token); //DID NOT WORK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! This is not usual, but if you add a backward trailing slash, it will keep the forward slash and it won't have a problem with the token.

`url('password/reset\/', [$token]);`

Thanks & Good luck!

Comment: Not convinced about this. It is certainly true that a constant string cannot end in a *backward* slash, as it escapes the closing quote. That would then result in a parsing error. But a forward slash? That should not have any issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

url helper function second parameter is parameter array to pass with the url. Instead of append parameters to end of the url.., you can use like bellow.

```
url('password/reset', [$token]);
```

Comment: I'm using php mail, I found a solution, the issue is unusual, but my approach worked! Vote up for you! :) thanks for the help! @Alupotha

Comment: Is the source of this issue down to what routes are defined for the application? If `password/{whatever}` is defined but not `password/reset/{token}` then the could laravel be trying and failing to map to known routes?